# Apache HTTP client: connection does not drop on sleep?

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-networking, server-push, apache-commons-httpclient

This is on Android. I create a long-lived connection to a server-push endpoint. I let the device go to sleep. When I wake it again (after 10 minutes or so), the connection is still blocking on the read.

However, I know the network went down. I'd expect the read to return with an error. Moreover, the read is no longer connected to the server endpoint.

This is very problematic for the server push scenario, since I can't tell if the connection is happily reading or dead.

Any ideas?

Comment: Given your one tag, can you confirm that you are using HttpClient for this? Have you tried another HTTP stack (`HttpUrlConnection`, `OkHTTP`, etc.)? Also, bear in mind that if the connection is mobile data, your behavior is expected, as the connection is not necessarily dropped.

Comment: this is a tablet w/ wifi and ethernet. no i have not tried other frameworks yet. given the overall system that's going to be a hard one.

Comment: Well, OkHTTP shouldn't be too hard, with their okhttp-apache module. http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: the complexity is we are setting up a log of security-related parameters with httpclient. point taken though, could be framework related and i may have to do as you suggest. thanks.